# Trigger Radio buttons Onclick function without using REF

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In React, Radio buttons onClick function should triggered automatically when value potentialMatch.isExactMatch is True.. **without using ref** for input type.

```
 <input type="radio"  onClick={() => {this.selectedInvitingOrg(param)}}
  name="potentialMatchRadioGroup" checked={potentialMatch.isExactMatch}/>
```

Comment: add `useEffect` and watch it

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate

Answer (score 0):

Please look it, how you can manage it

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-liskov-vjo92?file=/src/App.js

Comment: If you like my answer or you got any help from my answer, don't forget to consider up-vote and check this answer as the best answer for you by clicking on the right arrow, thanks!